# Calculating snow cover area using MODIS Snow Cover data MOD10A1

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis, time-series

I have a code of MODIS snow cover time series analysis, but I want to count the snow pixels covering my AOI and thereafter calculate the area and plot a chart

where to incorporate the code in this:

```
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1');
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate( '2011-01-01', '2020-12-31');

var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

var snowcover= modLSTday

var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
imageCollection: modLSTday,
region: AOI,
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 1000,
xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
.setOptions({
title: 'LST 2015 Time Series',
vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});
print(ts1);
```

Comment: "count the snow pixels", what does that mean? NDSI_Snow_Cover is a fractional layer, from 0 to 100. Is 1 a valid value for snow pixel? The question is too broad

Comment: @aldo_tapia I am also confused what threshold value to use to separate a non-snow area with snow cover area. Is there any other method you may suggest?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to download the documentation from [here](https://nsidc.org/data/MOD10A1/versions/6?qt-data_set_tabs=3#qt-data_set_tabs) (MOD10A1-V006-UserGuide_3.pdf). In this document you can see that **NDSI_Snow_Cover** takes values between 1 and 100. There are also considerations about how they are masked and how to interpreter false positives. I'm going to assume only **NDSI_Snow_Cover** values, a date range for one year and an arbitrary AOI in a USA region where there is snow cover. So, by using your code, it was printed **modLSTday** collection as chart. Snow is practically absent between June and October.

[image]

I modified your code for calculating snow cover (ha) for '2011-01-01' (possibly with snow cover) and '2011-06-01' (possibly without snow cover).

For '2011-01-01' (image 0 in collection), it was registered an area of 4557 ha; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

For '2011-06-01' (image 151 in collection), it was registered an area of 0 ha as expected; visualized in following picture:

[image]

So, function for calculating all areas in [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e8fe08b4eff14729a8211a5deceec15) is:

```
var allAreas = snowcover_lst.map(function (ele) {

  var image2 = ee.Image(ele).gte(1);

  var snowcover = ee.Image(ele).clip(AOI)
                     .updateMask(image2.eq(1));

  var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: AOI, 
    scale: 400,
    maxPixels: 1e8
  });

  var feats_area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: feats_area,
    scale: 400,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

  return snowArea.get('area');
  
});

print("allAreas", allAreas);
```

Running complete code in GEE code editor produces following result for all areas. You should interpreter adequately anomalous values before producing corresponding chart for areas. It's all.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

You can adapt ee.List transect line plot example in [this link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_array#code-editor-javascript-sample) for generating areas chart. Code snippet looks as follows:

```
// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: allAreas, axis: 0, xLabels: allDates})
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Areas as time function',
                  hAxis: {
                    title: 'Dates',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    title: 'Areas (ha)',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  colors: ['1d6b99'],
                  lineSize: 1,
                  pointSize: 0,
                  legend: {position: 'none'}
                });
print(chart);
```

After including above lines at the bottom of complete code and running it in GEE code editor, areas chart can be observed in following picture. You only have to find out a better format for dates list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, everything is fine except when I'm providing a time range of 1 yr it is giving an error "User memory limit exceeded". How to solve this?