# Export list (properties of image) from GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap, rgee

I tried to export a list, which is the values from the image from gee. I tried both  Export.image.toDrive() and Export.table.toDrive(). But they don't work. Below are the codes I am using (an example from another question: [Calculating snow cover area using MODIS Snow Cover data MOD10A1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432704/calculating-snow-cover-area-using-modis-snow-cover-data-mod10a1)).  The last "//Export to drive" is what I'm confused about.

```
var AOI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-108.05469055175782, 38.65469254359373],
          [-108.05469055175782, 38.5086927238664],
          [-107.69076843261719, 38.5086927238664],
          [-107.69076843261719, 38.65469254359373]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(AOI);
Map.addLayer(AOI);

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1');
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate( '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01'); //'2020-12-31'

var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

print(modLSTday);

var allDates = modLSTday.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

var allDates = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });
  
print("allDates", allDates);

var snowCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['black', '0dffff', '0524ff', 'ffffff'],
};

var snowcover_lst = modLSTday.toList(modLSTday.size());

var image = ee.Image(ee.List(snowcover_lst).get(151));

var image2 = image.gte(1);

var snowcover = image.clip(AOI)
                     .updateMask(image2.eq(1));

var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  geometry: area, 
  scale: 400,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

var area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: area,
  scale: 400,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

print('whole snow area (ha): ', snowArea.get('area'));

var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modLSTday,
  region: AOI,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
  title: 'LST 2015 Time Series',
  vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});

print(ts1);

Map.addLayer(snowcover, snowCoverVis, 'Snow Cover');

var allAreas = snowcover_lst.map(function (ele) {

  var image2 = ee.Image(ele).gte(1);

  var snowcover = ee.Image(ele).clip(AOI)
                     .updateMask(image2.eq(1));

  var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: AOI, 
    scale: 400,
    maxPixels: 1e8
  });

  var feats_area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: feats_area,
    scale: 400,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

  return snowArea.get('area');
  
});

print("allAreas", allAreas);

//Export to drive 
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: allAreas,
  folder: 'Google Earth',
  description: 'snow_cover_series',
fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: did you check in the `tasks` tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the list to an `ee.FeatureCollection` to export it using the `Export.table.toDrive` method.

An example using the null geometry:

```js
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null,{'list':allAreas})]),
  folder: 'Google Earth',
  description: 'snow_cover_series',
fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```