# GEE, error plot SNOW cover areas

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, plot, snow

I want to plot the maximum snow cover areas using MODIS, for that I am following the answer to a similar question someone asked months ago [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432704/calculating-snow-cover-area-using-modis-snow-cover-data-mod10a1/432765#432765)

But I have an error in the areas plotting section, this occurs when I change the reduce option from reducer.sum() to reducer.max()

And in the console, I get the following error:

*Error generating chart: xLabels must be the same length as the 1-D vectors from the array. xLabels is of length 2689 and the vectors are of length 0*.

Also,

*xLabels must be the same length as the 1-D vectors from the array. xLabels is of length 2689 and the vectors are of length 0.*

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

code below:

```
Map.centerObject(sca_zones);
Map.addLayer(sca_zones);

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD10A1'); 
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate( '2015-09-30', '2023-03-05'); //'2023-02-25'

var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

print(modLSTday);

var allDates = modLSTday.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

var allDates = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });
  
print("allDates", allDates);

var snowCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['black', '0dffff', '0524ff', 'ffffff'],
};

var snowcover_lst = modLSTday.toList(modLSTday.size());

var image = ee.Image(ee.List(snowcover_lst).get(1946)); // EL número ".get (151) significa el # de imagen en la colección 

var image2 = image.gte(1);

var snowcover = image.clip(sca_zones)
                     .updateMask(image2.eq(1));

var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  geometry: sca_zones, 
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

var area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: sca_zones,
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

print('whole snow area (ha): ', snowArea.get('area'));

var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modLSTday,
  region: sca_zones,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 100,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
  title: 'LST 2015 Time Series',
  vAxis: {title: 'snow cover'}});

print(ts1);

Map.addLayer(snowcover, snowCoverVis, 'Snow Cover');

var allAreas = snowcover_lst.map(function (ele) {

  var image2 = ee.Image(ele).gte(1);

  var snowcover = ee.Image(ele).clip(sca_zones)
                     .updateMask(image2.eq(1));

  var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: sca_zones, 
    scale: 100,
    maxPixels: 1e8
  });

  var feats_area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);

  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: feats_area,
    scale: 100,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

  return snowArea.get('area');
  
});

print("allAreas", allAreas);


// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: allAreas, axis: 0, xLabels: allDates})
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Areas as time function',
                  hAxis: {
                    title: 'Dates',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    title: 'Areas (km2)',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  colors: ['1d6b99'],
                  lineSize: 1,
                  pointSize: 0,
                  legend: {position: 'none'}
                });
print(chart);
```

Comment: Include `sca_zones`. With some random snowy area, the scripts runs without problems.